# Get list of user sessions using a particular remote app using powershell

Tags: powershell, remote-desktop

We're putting together a powershell script to deploy new versions of applications onto our servers. We need to get a list of all the `RDUserSession` objects which are running our application.

We're finding that the `Get-RDUserSession` command with the -Collection option will return all users on the system, including administrators logged in remotely, but not running a RemoteApp.

What we want to do is kick off all users who are running our Remote Applications so we can perform an update.

Right now we get the list of `RDUserSessions` and send them all a messaage using `Send-RDUserMessage`, but we're finding that we are also sending the message, and booting off, admins that are trying to run the script.

Is there a way to get the list of applications running in a `RDUserSession`?

Comment: That doesn't connect it to the session though.

Answer (score 0):

```
#Load your applications in an array
$arr = @("a.exe", "b.exe")

#Get the RD User Sessions
$rdsessions = Get-RDUserSession

#Create a blank array to capture your users
$usrarr = @()

#Loop through the applications in the array
foreach($app in $arr)
{
    #Loop through each of the sessions.
    foreach($rdsession in $rdsessions)
    {
        #Check the application
        $proc = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_process -Filter "Name = $app"

        #compare the rdsession with the applicaitons session.
        if($rdsession.id -eq $proc.SessionId)
        {
            #Load the true to the hash
            $obj = New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{User = $rdsession.UserName; Application = $app}
            $usrarr += $obj 
        }
    }
}

#Now you can take the data in the array and send a message.
Foreach($usr in $usrarr)
{
    #send an email or a net send message.
    #code here....
}
```

Comment: Won't Get-WmiObject return a list of processes?

Comment: wait... yes with the sessions associated with it. You'd have to loop through that as well.

Comment: Did a bit more research, why wouldn't I user Get-Process instead of Get-WmiObject?

Comment: Process doesn't have the session ID.

Comment: Actually, Get-Process does appear to have the SessionId. Try this:

Get-Process | Select *